# Is there a way to update VS' CSS validation to 3.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, validation, css

I'm getting warnings about CSS3.0 properties like text-overflow.  Is there a way to validate against 3.0?

---

HTML5 and CSS3 support is coming to VS2010 in SP1.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120621010521/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2011/01/27/html5-amp-css3-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1.aspx)

---

And now its here.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210/view/Reviews/0?showReviewForm=True

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, you can define your own Visual Studio Intellisense schema for CSS. I’m not sure if VS will then validate against that, or only use it for code completion.

Might be worth making a minimal one and seeing if it gets used for validation.

[Custom CSS Intellisense Schema in Visual Studio 2005 and 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2007/10/19/how-to-create-custom-css-intellisense-schema-in-visual-studio-2005-and-2008.aspx)

I don’t know of an easy way to validate against CSS 3 yet though. CSS 3 is a large, modular spec, and most of it is very much still in flux, despite some decent browser support for some properties.

http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work

Comment: Dear innertube searchers...  The future is now.  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210/view/Reviews/0?showReviewForm=True

Answer (score 3):

To turn off validation in VS2008 I had to go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > CSS > CSS Specific and uncheck "Detect errors".

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210/view/Reviews/0?showReviewForm=True!

I've just installed it on my computer and works fine on Visual Studio 2010 sp1

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe so. But you can turn the validation off if you want. Go to Tools > Options. Expand Text Editor > HTML > Validation. This screen shows all the different validation targets. Uncheck Show Errors if you want to turn the validation off.